# Problem with grouping items in print composer- QGIS 2.14

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2.14, grouping, element

This is print composer:

[image]

when i group all elements with "group items" and minimize the frame- some items step out from the frame:

[image]

How can i group all items, and still maintain the same ratio of distances between all items, so all items remain in their position?

In ArcGIS it is possible.

Comment: Make sure you get the legend in the group?

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand you

Comment: It does not look like you included the legend in your group

Comment: i mean the legend is in the white area of the composer- it does not in the frame of the map. i don't want to locate the legend in the map extent.